# Android Icon Duplicates in Application Dock

Tags: android, icons, duplicates

For some odd reason, my project is generating two icons, same name, launches the same project, in the app drawer. I can't figure out what is causing this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[Link to screenshot](http://gimli.morningside.edu/~jcf002/images/android_duplicate_icon.png)

The M in the white circle is my default icon. If you view the screenshot, you'll see it appears twice. I've checked the applications area, and it is only installed once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have two activities in your manifest marked as launch activities?  That would cause two different launcher icons to appear.